# Text 'fadeIn' animation

Tags: java, animation, javafx

So I tried creating an animation which fades a string in (from black) on screen, but when I run it, it doesn't seem to work properly. I'm not getting any errors, just a black screen (the stage is black).

Here is the code:

```
public static void fadeIn(String string, Text tBox) {
    final IntegerProperty counter = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
    final BoolProp firstLoop = new BoolProp(false);

    Color fadeIn[] = new Color[16];

    String hexVal = "";
    String hash = "#";

    for (int i = 0; i > 10; i += 1) {
        hexVal = "";

        if (i == 10) 
            break;

        for (int c = 0; c >6; c += 1) {
            hexVal += i;
        }

        fadeIn[i] = Color.web(hash + hexVal);
    }
    fadeIn[10] = Color.web("#aaaaaa");
    fadeIn[11] = Color.web("#bbbbbb");
    fadeIn[12] = Color.web("#cccccc");
    fadeIn[13] = Color.web("#dddddd");
    fadeIn[14] = Color.web("#eeeeee");
    fadeIn[15] = Color.web("#ffffff");

    Timeline line = new Timeline();
    KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.05), event -> {
        if (counter.get() == 16) {
            line.stop();
        } else {
            if (firstLoop.get()) {
                firstLoop.set(false);
                tBox.setText(string);
            }
            tBox.setFill(fadeIn[counter.get()]);
            counter.set(counter.get()+1);
        }
    });
    line.getKeyFrames().add(frame);
    line.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    line.play();
}
```

And it's being referenced as follows:

```
public class Tester extends Application {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        VBox box = new VBox();

        Text text = new Text();

        box.getChildren().addAll(text);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(box, 500, 500, Color.BLACK));
        stage.show();

        Animations.fadeIn("Testing 123", text);
    }
}
```

The class BoolProp is as follows (I know one already exists, but I didn't have access to the documentation when I was writing the method.):

```
public class BoolProp {
    private boolean val;

    public BoolProp() {
        val = false;
    }

    public BoolProp(boolean val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public boolean get() {
        return val;
    }

    public void set(boolean val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code. Lets get to them one by one :

1. The for loops inside the `fadeIn()` are incorrect.

Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i > 10; i += 1)
```

This loop will never execute since the condition will always be false. What you are looking for is :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

Similarly, fix the other loop as well.

2. Inside `fadeIn()`, you initialize the `firstLoop` to `false` and then inside the KeyFrame constructor, you try to check if the value is `true`, which leads to never setting the text on the Text.
3. There are few other issues with initializing of String, which we can overlook for now.

If you fix 1 and 2, you should be good to have a running application.